# TD API - TDA trouble retrieving historical quotes

Tags: python, ameritrade

I'm trying to download historical close pricing for various stocks using TDA module in python.

I'm using a datetime that looks like this:
`test = datetime.datetime(2023, 10, 20, 15, 59, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'US/Eastern' LMT-1 day, 19:04:00 STD>)`

when I run this code I get the following output:

`response = client.get_price_history_every_day('SPY', start_datetime=test, end_datetime=test) response`

```
<Response [200 ]>
```

looking as to what the Response [200] means and what I'm doing wrong.  Thanks in advance.